# Delete multiple records on Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I've a class with over 110 million records on Parse and want to delete 99% of it based on one rule :
"state"!=1

I  have set some background jobs that do this record by record, but are too slow and the class gets slowly bigger.

Is there any way to delete them faster? 
Maybe delete all objects before a set date?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try [Parse.Object.destroyAll(list)](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_destroyAll) - at least it should be more convenient to use.

Comment: Are you implying that he can select 110 million rows in one fell swoop? Parse limits you to 1000 records per query, so he would be making thousands of read queries to delete.

Comment: No, I am not. Cristian asked for a way to delete records faster, and this is what Parse.Object.destroyAll() does help with. Instead of "fetch 1 - delete 1", he can "fetch a 1000 - delete a 1000". It would still take a lot of time, yes, but this **is** a faster way to delete records, and as such it is a perfectly valid answer. It is not ideal, but it is better than no answer. If anyone knows a better way - sure, I'd be happy to know it too.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answere comes late but it's for every one who will be in that case.
I've been in the same case and I came to conclusion that parse cannot be great for this kind of operation.

This is not the parse fault, since every ORM are not very much suitable for deleting more than 1 millions rows.
The only way for me is to use native query directly on the database. You will gonna have the best performance you could ever get.
If you are using mongo db here is an example how you could implement it based on 2 dates.

```
require('dotenv').config(); // include .env file
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

main();
async function main(){
 const dbUrl=process.env.DATABASE_URI;

 const client= new MongoClient(dbUrl);
try{
    await client.connect();
    let dateEnd=new Date();
    let dateStart=new Date();
    dateStart.setDate(dateStart.getDate()-20);
    await deleteAllBeetweenDate(client,dateStart,dateEnd);

}catch(e){
    console.error(e);
}finally{
    await client.close();
}

}

async function deleteAllBeetweenDate(client,dateStart, dateEnd) {
    const result = await client.db("test").collection("BigTable")
        .deleteMany({ "day": {$gte:dateStart, $lte: dateEnd } });
    console.log(`${result.deletedCount} document(s) was/were deleted.`);
}
```

Next you just have to integrate it inside your cloud/main.js file.
You could improve the request performance using index on the fields used to filter the rows to remove.